# Booking within sabre red with the same PCC code

Tags: sabre

We are a new travel agent, we are integrating API into our backend platform so that we can provide access to our staff and agent to manage booking .  I want clarifications on the following.

1. Can an API fully replace the functionality of Sabre Red so that we do not have to order Sabre red for each subagent?
2. IF yes then what API we should integrate.
3. IF no, what API what is the best solution so that our subagent can work independently, without accessing other agents booking.

Please clarify on one more option. Is there a way for our staff in our office with a different login that they cannot access another staff booking within sabre red with the same PCC code.

In short, we are thinking of a module where we give independent API access to all our sub-agents, and they can work independently without getting us involved for, e.g. changes to booking, cancelling the booking, 
booking.

Answer (score 0):

to give you a brief answer to your questions:

1) In theory yes - from a more practical view: No. Problems will arise if you are e.g. going down the paths of ancillaries, specific pricings etc. you will end up reinventing sabre red.

For more simple usecases like booking some RT etc yes.

2) See answer above for a simple shopping usecase start of with Bargain Finder MAX, Orchestrated Airbook and Intin retrieve. This is the most basic usecase if you are using a consolidator who issues your ticket. Are you ticketing yourself?

3) As all bookings within a PCC are accessible for all agents you would need to set up a PCC per Agent and bridge the PCC's where a connection is needed

The one more thing see question 3)

Hope i could help you a little bit